# str_replace won't replace arabic characters

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$utf8_string = 'مع السلامة مع السلامة مع السلامة مع السلامة مع السلامة مع السلامة مع السلامة السلامة الرائعة على الطويلة ';
echo $utf8_string;
echo'<br/><br/>';

$patterns = array("على", "مع");
$replacements   = array("", "");

$r_string = str_replace($patterns, $replacements, $utf8_string);

//echo $r_string;
print_r ($r_string);
echo'<br/>';
//$words = preg_split( "/ ( |مع|على) /",$r_string);
$words = explode(" ",$r_string);

$num = count($words);
echo 'There are <strong>'.$num.'</strong> words.';
?>
```

I have this code to count the number of words in an arabic sentence.however i want to remove some words and count the rest.i tried to use str_replace, but this way is counting the number of words of the original sentence.
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
$num = count(
    explode(
        " ", 
        str_replace(
            $word, //Word you want to remove from your text.
            "",
            $string //String you want the word to be removed from.
        )
    )
);
```

Or even:

```
$num = count(
    explode(
        " ", 
        str_replace(
            array("word1", "word2", [...]), //Words you want to remove from your text.
            "",
            $string //String you want the word to be removed from.
        )
    )
);
```

---

EDIT: As pointed out, the above won't work. I tried pinpointing where the error is, and apparently **`str_replace` can't handle arabic characters**, even though `explode` can. [PHP is not reliable with non-ascii characters.](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/#text-1)

What you can do, alternatively, is:

```
$num = Count(explode(" ", $utf8_string)) - Count(array_intersect(explode(" ", $utf8_string), $patterns))
```

It should return the value you want.

You could also try writing your own string replacement function, but I would advice against it, seeing you'd have to manually loop through your array and compare each word. Doing so should take longer to run, and make it much more verbose.

---

Coming here to warn yall that the correct way to handle this is with the `mbstring` extension (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php). Please use this extension, no the ugly hack/workaround above.

Comment: What was the output? Did it count all the words? Some number that was neither the expected result nor the total amount of words (before replacing)?

Comment: it count the number of words in the first sentence,which is 18.the output i should get is 10 after removing the words

Answer (score 1):

You need to "remove duplicates spaces" after removing some words and before counting spaces with explode. Trim (or a similar regex) is needed for spaces on front and end of the string

```
    $r_string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/u',' ',$r_string));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$num = str_word_count($r_string);`

Instead of `$num = count($words);`

Comment: str_word_count doesnt read arabic words.That's what i realized bcz i tried it a lot of times and it didnt work